# Java database IDs - primitive or wrapped type

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm working with Eclipse, Java, MySQL, and use JPA just to generate Entities. I write the DAOs by hand.

For database IDs, I use INT in MySQL and have been using Long on Java. Is there an advantage or disadvantage to using the Long type versus just a primitive long? I made some assumptions and went with Long. I'm just verifying my assumptions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One difference is that `Long` can be `null`, but `long` can't be (it will be `0`). I feel its good to have `Long` because you can do simple checks like whether the entity is not yet persisted -  by checking whether `id == null`;